# Add HTTP header parameters in JavaFX browser

Tags: java, javafx, http-headers, user-agent

Java version: 7u45, OS: Mac OS

I'm trying to set the "User-agent" parameter in `HttpHeader` on JavaFX browser using `WebEngine`.

I want to set the "User-agent" header before a call to

```
webEngine.load(url);
```

Comment: You cannot set `User-Agent` prior to JavaFX8. Please upgrade to JDK8 !

Comment: Because of some Project issue I can't update to JDK 1.8. IS there another way to set User-Agent?

Comment: Unfortunately, [setting user agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userAgentProperty) is available only after JavaFX 8